# Is G a group under the operation of modular multiplication?

Tags: group-theory, modular-arithmetic

for $G=Z_{77} \setminus \{0\}$.

I'm mainly getting caught up on the notation, as I've never seen it before. Would this be the group $\{1,2,3.....76\}$?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is not a group because 11 does not have an inverse; perhaps it was a reference to just the set and not as a group.

Comment: Thank you! That's very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of units (i.e. elements that possess  multiplicative inverses) forms a group under modular multiplication. For some $a \in \mathbb{Z}_{n}$, $a$ is a unit if and only if $\gcd(a,n) = 1$.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was thinking, but my notes and textbook were being vague.